# Create custom mail compose view (User Interface) in IOS

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ios6

Currently i am working to create a mail composer view without using MFMailComposerview.
My requirements are that i should have to,cc,bcc fields with a webview as as body, while zooming the webview its should behave in the same way as native mail behaves, i.e the "to,cc,bbc" field should also move proportionally.

Concern is just related to the UI not functional part.

Any suggestions on how to start with this thing.

Regards,
Suhail

Comment: If there is no difference in Native and Your Custom class (As your question says), why not saving time by using Native, which is already there? Also, You have to implement email id suggestions for to, cc, bcc fields,; Which is already there, built-in!!

Comment: Well, i am surprised to see downvote. Anyways if anyone has the same requirement, please refer to VENTokenField (https://github.com/venmo/VENTokenField), it will of great help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For UI Part (XIB), you can start with following:

- You can have a `ViewController` subclass with `UINavigationBar`.
- Add `UITableView` (of plain style) on that `UIViewController`
- Make `UITableViewCell` custom subclass for To,CC,BCC fields.
- Make another `UITableViewCell` custom subclass for Contents.

For the last point, You can use `UIScrollView` having `UItextView` and/or `UIWebView` based upon your requirements for the content/body of your email.

After all this, UI Components working as per your expectation; you can move on the functional part, which is define (though in broad sense) in @user2235613's answer.

Good luck.

Comment: The problem with this approach is that when the email body is large the cell height can be very big and according to Apple's doc (https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITableViewDelegate/tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:) the max height for a tableview cell is 2009